# jquery .html() removes trailing spaces

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I want to set `"someting           "` as the html inside a div, but .html() seem to remove the trailing spaces.

It's inside a `contenteditable` div, so when the users starts typing there's a space missing between "something" and what he types.

**HTML**

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('div#text').html('something          ');
```

This shows "something_" inside the div, but when you start typing it appears right next to the rest of the text.

Comment: Try using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) instead

Comment: @spider Basically, `innerHTML` has the same effect as jQuery's `.html()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to set visible spaces in HTML, they should be in the form of `&nbsp;`, e.g.

```
​$("#text").html("something&nbsp;&nbsp;")​​​​;
```

An option is to make basic spaces transformation using your own function:

```
function spaceToNbsp(str) {
    return str.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
}

$("#text").html(spaceToNbsp("something  "))​​​​;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NAWY3/

Comment: That's nice, I just need to add an "if last char is space, then replace it with a non breaking space".

Comment: (I can't change all spaces, or it will overflow to the right)

Comment: @Manu No problem. The regular expression may help: `replace(/ $/, "&nbsp;")`.

Comment: You might also try wrapping in pre tags, because they should maintain spaces.  Another alternative is the CSS white-space: pre; rule.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&nbsp;` instead of spaces:

```
$('#div_id').html("something&nbsp;");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like it using `css`

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="test"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#test:before{
    content: '>\0000a0\0000a0';
    /*or  content: 'Something\0000a0\0000a0';*/
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/eyefur/1/edit).